# Reading IIS logs

Tags: asp.net, iis, webserver

I see this header information intermittently shown throughout my log file:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2013-10-25 15:56:31
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
```

I always though that such header information would only be displayed at the top of the file. Why is it shown intermittently in the file? I usually see this occur after there is a time lapse between the previous log entry and the one that comes after this.

Comment: If one site is not have traffic, the IIS, close the log file. Also close it on restart, something change on site, etc. On every new open for write the IIS is write this header because on the middle time you may have change what the headers can be. Also think from the programmer side, to take the desition to not write again the header, is must know some how that the header exist and is correct. How to do that on text file ?

Comment: IIS reset will also trigger such headers.